# How to control cancel subscribe Ionic In app Purchase

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, in-app-purchase, android-inapp-purchase

Need Help with InAppPurchase2

My code works fine, but I have one problem. When the user cancel the subscribe I can´t identify this, but when a restart the app this qestion is identify and app works again.

Explain better:
1 - App start and load store and products. OK
2 - User order subscribe and the app finish this and product go to "owned" status. Ok
3 - User cancel the subscribe on Google Play, but when my app call store.refresh(), product still stay "owned" status. PROBLEM
4 - when the app restart the product return to "valid" state.

Debuging I can see the when.approved still calling after I call finish() until app restart.

Is there any way to restart load store?

```
    configurarProdutos() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {      

          // Registra os produtos da loja
          this.store.register([
            {id: "mensal_basico",
            type: this.store.PAID_SUBSCRIPTION}
          ]);

          this.registrarEventos('mensal_basico')

          this.store.refresh();
        });    
      }

  registrarEventos(produto) {
    this.store.when(produto)
    .approved( (product: IAPProduct) => {
      product.finish()
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

After some hours trying to find solution, finally I can share this with you.

Everything is ok with the code, but get signature information is not easy. So the InAppPurchase2 plugin works with other service: Fovea.Billing. The cust is lower and have a good number to start free. I tested a lot and liked the service.

Ok, let´s see the solution I implemented.

1. Create and configure an account on the Fovea.Billing.

   - android need this configuration: [Documentation](https://billing.fovea.cc/connect-with-google-publisher-api/)
2. Define url to verify.

   - This URL can be found at the Fovea configurations.

Example: 
store.validator =
"https://validator.fovea.cc/v1/validate?appName=&apiKey=";

3. To enabled validation, follow this steps
   Receipt validation is being called when you do p.verify(). Some demo code omit this line, so make sure that p.verify() is called from the approved event, then p.finish() called from the verified event.

   store.when('product')
     .approved(p => p.verify())
     .verified(p => p.finish());

After this you can know the situation of subcribe. If ths subscribe is expired the event verified is not trigger.